# PGP File Encryption

Tags: encryption, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

Using Bouncy Castle to encrypt a file, I am having trouble generating the private/public keys. The public key needs to be in the OpenSSH or RFC4716 format the problem is when I use ssh-keygen to create the keys they cannot be used to encrypt the file. Why is this? I even used ssh-keygen to export the keys into the RFC4716 format and still i was unable to use it to  encrypt the file.

Comment: PGP keys are incompatible with SSH keys (format). You need special code to convert between the formats. Edit your question and add the code you already have.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert commented, these formats are not compatible. For PGP file encryption I will use the normally generated keys. Thanks again Robert.